# Bind socket with available port number

Tags: c, sockets

I am working one a socket programming using c code. I am trying to create a server with any ip address and any available port. That is I use as following:

```
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
serv_addr.sin_port = ntohs(0);
```

As far I study, I know if I use this server configuration in bind, then I will have my socket bind with available port number by the machine itself. What I do is:

```
if (bind(bridgeSockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))
        < 0)
    printf("ERROR on binding");
```

and when I test my ip address and port number, I got as like following:

```
IP Address: 127.0.0.1
Port Number: 0
```

This is completely unexpected that I have port number 0.

Here I also provide the continuous code too:

```
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

// configure server information
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
serv_addr.sin_port = ntohs(0);

// bind socket with server information
if (bind(bridgeSockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))
        < 0)
    printf("ERROR on binding");

// turn to passive
listen(bridgeSockfd, 5);

name = gethostbyaddr(&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
        sizeof serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, AF_INET);
strcpy(bridgeIP, name->h_name);
bridgePortNo = ntohs(serv_addr.sin_port);
```

Can anyone help me out where I am doing wrong to have an automatic port assignment from the machine instead of getting 0 always.

*Note: I am using ubuntu operating system through a virtual machine.*

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bind() doesn't write to sockaddr. Call getsockname() to find out where it bound to.

```
socklen_t size = sizeof(serv_addr);
getsockname(bridgeSockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, &size);
```

Comment: Thank you. But can you give a little bit details about why me previous attempt is not write, or what actually this method does.

Comment: getsockname() copies the bound address of the socket into the struct.

Answer (score 1):

`gethostbyaddr()` doesn't return the port number of a listening socket. You should be using `getsockname()`.

Comment: Thank you. But can you give a little bit details about why me previous attempt is not write, or what actually this method does.

Comment: The *man* page does a far better job of that than I could possibly do here.